# How to update control inside ControlGroup Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-formbuilder

any one have a plnkr or a simple example on how to updateValue Control inside a ControlGroup (ANGULAR 2 BETA 7) ??

i want to change the value of my Zipcode on my adress controlGroup, this is what i've tried:

```
(<Control>this.form.controls['address'].zip.label).updateValue("3000");
```

&

```
this.form.controls.address.zip.label.updateValue("3000");
```

neither did work, any one have a hint ?

here is how i creat the form :

```
this.form = fb.group({
           adress: fb.group({
            zip: fb.group({
                label: []
            })
        });
```

Comment: Please provide code that shows how you create your form.

Comment: sure, check out my question

Comment: What is `this.form`?

Comment: sorry i've reposted it

Comment: try `thsi.form.find('zip.label'').updateValue("3000");` Don't remember about these old versions.

Comment: what about adress ? it's a control group inside my form group

Comment: You can also try `address.zip.label` or `address/zip/label`. Not sure. This stuff changed quite a bit.

Comment: thanks a lot you've saved me :) it did worked with :(<Control>this.form.find('adress/zip/label')).updateValue("3000");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to use `find`:

```
(<Control>this.form.find('adress/zip/label')).updateValue("‌​3000");
```